# Stack Overflow and Opera 11

Tags: support, opera

I'm using [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) 11 as my default browser, but when I'm on a Stack Overflow page I cannot, for example, open comments (pressing **add / show 6 more comments** does nothing). It works in [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome). Also, I have the same problem when clicking **Post Your Question**.

I have to use Chrome when submitting something to Stack Overflow.

It looks like some problem with JavaScript or Ajax.

Comment: Same problem with IE9.

Comment: I am using opera 11 and do not have this problem.  Ensure you have javascript enabled by pressing F12 and making sure Javascript is checked.

Comment: I've tried with Opera 11 (x86_64/Linux) and appears to work. `2.6.35.10-74.fc14.x86_64`.

Comment: I have not experienced this with either Opera (my primary home browser) or IE8 (my work browser).

Comment: Sometimes experience the same problem. And not only with stackoverflow..It seems Opera's problem with some form submitting..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar experience. However, it was due to a problem with my Opera user JavaScript that caused the required JavaScript-files to not be loaded. Anyway, the problem is that

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

doesn't load the jQuery stuff.

In other words, try to figure out if the mentioned file actually gets loaded or causes an error, which prevents the jQuery stuff to be initialized properly.

As far as the OP is concerned, I cannot provide help, but at least you now know what's causing it ;).

Answer (score 1):

Works for me, with a brand new Opera 11 install with default settings on Mac. So it has to be your settings...